# Select records from vertical row and transform horizontal row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on a SQL Server query to fetch the last Badge_In_Out_Time of the list of users who will be working on multiple task codes.

task_mgmt - tablename

Table Columns as follows

| Task_Sn | UserName | Task_Code | Action | Badge_IN_OUT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | BLOG | START | 2021-07-15 08:11:45.000 |
| 2 | Andy | BLOG | END | 2021-07-15 10:11:45.000 |
| 3 | Becky | ACCTS | START | 2021-07-15 11:11:45.000 |
| 4 | Chris | TAX | START | 2021-07-15 12:11:45.000 |
| 5 | Andy | SOCMEDIA | START | 2021-07-15 12:15:45.000 |
| 6 | Becky | ACCTS | END | 2021-07-15 12:25:45.000 |

I am excepting the result

| UserName | Task_Code | Badge_IN_TIME | Badge_OUT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | BLOG | 2021-07-15 08:11:45.000 | 2021-07-15 10:11:45.000 |
| Becky | ACCTS | 2021-07-15 11:11:45.000 | 2021-07-15 12:25:45.000 |
| Chris | TAX | 2021-07-15 12:11:45.000 |  |
| Andy | SOCMEDIA | 2021-07-15 12:15:45.000 |  |

I really couldn't come up with any query for this. I am a beginner in SQL and I know CRUD operations. This seems to be super complex for me.

```
Select UserName,
       Task_Code,
       Badge_In_Time,
       Badge_Out_Time
from task_mgmt
order by Badge_IN_OUT_TIME desc
```

Comment: I really couldn't come up with any query for this. I am a beginner in SQL and i know CRUD operations. This seems to be super complex for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a simple pivot by aggregating your rows to the desired level (`UserName`,`TaskCode`) and then pivoting using `MAX` or `MIN(CASE WHEN .... END)`

Like so:

```
SELECT 
    tm.UserName
    ,tm.Task_Code
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN tm.Action = 'START' THEN tm.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME ELSE NULL END) AS Badge_IN_TIME
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN tm.Action = 'END' THEN tm.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME ELSE NULL END) AS Badge_OUT_TIME 
FROM 
    task_mgmt AS tm 
GROUP BY 
    tm.UserName
    ,tm.Task_Code
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this solution and let you know. Really appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem,** the islands are pairs of `START` and `END`.

There are a number of solutions. Here, I have assumed that `START` always defines the beginning of each group, and there may or may not be an `END`.

We can calculate a grouping number for each island by using a windowed `COUNT`, partitioning by `UserName` and `Task_Code`. We then simply group up also by the new grouping number, and pivot the timestamp.

```sql
SELECT
  t.UserName,
  t.Task_Code
  MIN(CASE WHEN t.Action = 'START' THEN t.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME END) Badge_IN_TIME,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.Action = 'END'   THEN t.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME END) Badge_OUT_TIME
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Action = 'START' THEN 1 END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY t.UserName, t.Task_Code
            ORDER BY t.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) grp
    FROM task_mgmt t
) t
GROUP BY
  t.UserName,
  t.Task_Code
  t.grp;
```