# Find Total Mins Between Multiple Swipe In/Swipe Out Timestamps - Select multiple records from vertical row and transform horizontal row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on a SQL Server query to fetch the Badge Out Time - Bade In Time of the list of users who will be working on multiple task codes.

task_mgmt - tablename

Table Columns as follows

| Task_Sn | UserName | Task_Code | Action | Badge_IN_OUT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | BLOG | START | 2021-07-20 08:11:45.000 |
| 2 | Andy | BLOG | END | 2021-07-20 10:11:45.000 |
| 3 | Becky | ACCTS | START | 2021-07-20 11:11:45.000 |
| 4 | Becky | ACCTS | END | 2021-07-20 12:11:45.000 |
| 5 | Andy | BLOG | START | 2021-07-20 12:15:45.000 |
| 6 | Andy | BLOG | END | 2021-07-20 12:25:45.000 |
| 7 | Andy | BLOG | START | 2021-07-20 12:25:00.000 |
| 8 | Becky | ACCTS | START | 2021-07-20 13:00:00.000 |
| 9 | Becky | ACCTS | END | 2021-07-20 13:30:00.000 |

I am excepting the result

| UserName | Task_Code | Badge_IN_TIME | Badge_OUT_TIME | TOTAL_MINS_SPENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | BLOG | 2021-07-20 12:25:55.000 |  | 135 |
| Becky | ACCTS | 2021-07-20 13:00:00.000 | 2021-07-20 13:30:00.000 | 90 |

I really couldn't come up with any query for this. I am a beginner in SQL and I know CRUD operations. This seems to be super complex for me.

```
Select UserName,
       Task_Code,
       Badge_In_Time,
       Badge_Out_Time,
       (Badge_Out_Time - Badge_In_Time) as TOTAL_TIME_SPENT
from task_mgmt
order by Badge_IN_OUT_TIME desc
```

Since Andy is currently badge-in and not badge-out yet, so the latest badge-out timestamp is being calculated as **[ getdate() - badge-in ]** as LastTransaction Mins (5 mins)

[image]

Comment: _"I am working on a SQL Server query"_  Then please remove the 'oracle' tag ....

Comment: @EdStevens I have removed oracle from the tag list. Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select records from vertical row and transform horizontal row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401086/select-records-from-vertical-row-and-transform-horizontal-row) **Your previous question,** how is it different from this, and what are you struggling with from those answers? Don't just repost

Comment: @EdStevens Did you get a chance to help me on the script?

Comment: @JSLover Can you please have a look in my answer and clarify these points. 
Add the derivation details for the Badge_IN_TIME Badge_OUT_TIME columns in  your question or as a comment. So I can try to get these column values as well.  You have explained the calculation for TOTAL_MINS_SPENT nicely. Do the same for Badge_IN_TIME Badge_OUT_TIME as well as I am not sure about what you need to display there. Thanks

Comment: On Task_Sn 1, Andy starts his timer for the task BLOG where we assume row1 of BADGE_IN_OUT_TIME AS BADGE_IN_TIME.

Comment: ON Task_Sn_2, Andy stopped working for the task BLOG after working for 2 hours where we assume row2 of BADGE_IN_OUT_TIME AS BADGE_OUT_TIME.

Comment: Again, Andy starts back to work on Task_Sn5 and ends with Task_Sn6 . And again he started working on Task_Sn:7 and till now he works on the task "BLOG".

Comment: _"@EdStevens Did you get a chance to help me on the script?"_  Sorry, I don't do mssql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample data the last start time for Andy was earlier than his last end time, therefore creating an overlap.  I am making the assumption this is incorrect given how you described your logic for calculating total minutes. Therefore in my sample table I have adjusted accordingly.

Consider the following:

I used a derived table with the **LEAD()** function to capture what the next date and action where.  I Used this in my outer query to determine the minutes used based on what my next action was going to be.

I used a **CROSS APPLY** to determine what the **MAX** Start and End dates where for the username and task.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(Task_Sn int,  UserName varchar(20),Task_Code varchar(10), Action varchar(10), Badge_IN_OUT_TIME datetime)
INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES
(1,'Andy','BLOG','START','2021-07-20 08:11:45.000'),
(2,'Andy','BLOG','END','2021-07-20 10:11:45.000'),
(3,'Becky','ACCTS','START','2021-07-20 11:11:45.000'),
(4,'Becky','ACCTS','END','2021-07-20 12:11:45.000'),
(5,'Andy','BLOG','START','2021-07-20 12:15:45.000'),
(6,'Andy','BLOG','END','2021-07-20 12:25:45.000'),
(7,'Andy','BLOG','START','2021-07-20 12:35:00.000'),
(8,'Becky','ACCTS','START','2021-07-20 13:00:00.000'),
(9,'Becky','ACCTS','END','2021-07-20 13:30:00.000')


SELECT X.UserName,X.Task_Code ,Y.ST_TIME Badge_IN_TIME
    ,CASE WHEN Y.ST_TIME > Y.ED_TIME THEN NULL ELSE Y.ED_TIME END Badge_OUT_TIME 
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Action = 'START' AND NX_ACTION= 'END' THEN DATEDIFF(minute,Badge_IN_OUT_TIME, NX_TIME) 
         WHEN ACTION = 'START' AND NX_ACTION IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(minute,Badge_IN_OUT_TIME, GETDATE())
         END) TotalMinutesSpent
FROM(
    select *,
    LEAD(Badge_IN_OUT_TIME,1) OVER(Partition by UserName,Task_Code  ORDER BY  Badge_IN_OUT_TIME) NX_TIME,
    LEAD(ACTION,1) OVER(Partition by UserName,Task_Code ORDER BY  Badge_IN_OUT_TIME) NX_ACTION
    from #tmp
    ) X
CROSS APPLY(SELECT UserName,
                MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'START' THEN Badge_IN_OUT_TIME END) ST_TIME,
                MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'END' THEN Badge_IN_OUT_TIME END) ED_TIME 
                FROM #tmp t1 
                    WHERE t1.UserName = X.UserName 
                            and t1.Task_Code = X.Task_Code 
                GROUP BY UserName, Task_Code
            ) Y
GROUP BY X.USERNAME,X.Task_Code ,Y.ST_TIME,Y.ED_TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT UserName,
       Task_Code,
       task_in.Task_Sn as Task_In_Sn,
       TOUT.Task_Out_Sn,
       task_in.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME as Time_In_Raw,
       FORMAT(task_in.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME, 'hh\:mm') as Task_In_Time,
       FORMAT(TOUT.Task_Out_Time, 'hh\:mm') as Task_Out_Time,
       DATEDIFF(minute, task_in.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME,
                 ISNULL(TOUT.Task_Out_Time, GETDATE())) as LengthOfTime
FROM task_mgmt task_in
    OUTER APPLY (
       SELECT TOP 1
            task_out.Task_Sn as Task_Out_Sn,
            task_out.Badge_IN_OUT_TIME as Task_Out_Time
        FROM task_mgmt task_out
        WHERE task_out.Action = 'END' AND
              task_out.UserName = task_in.UserName AND
              task_out.Task_Sn > task_in.Task_Sn
        ORDER BY Task_Sn
    ) TOUT
WHERE task_in.Action = 'START'
ORDER BY Task_Sn
```

Note that the `OUTER APPLY` looks for the first record with a larger `Task_Sn` that matches the other criteria (I could have used `Badge_IN_OUT_TIME` instead of `Task_Sn`, but integers are a little nicer and possibly more efficient).

Note also the `ISNULL` in the `DATEDIFF` that substitutes `GETDATE` when the date is `NULL`.

If you need to sum multiple intervals, you can use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I provided the answer but I know there is two columns missing in the expected result.

Note: These ***two columns Badge_IN_TIME    Badge_OUT_TIME*** are missing as I am not sure about the what you want to retrieve for these two columns, If you can clarify the result and expected values for these tow columns as the way you showed for the TOTAL_TIME_SPENT I can edit the Question and add these two columns derivation as well.

After adding the logic to the above mentioned columns This is what my query returns. I think The expected answer is also haveing some issue as it should in line with the logic.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
  UserName
  , Task_Code
  ,( SELECT  MAX(Badge_IN_OUT_Time ) from  task_mgmt E where E.UserName =  A.UserName   and A.Task_code =  E.Task_Code and    [Action] ='Start'  )  Badge_IN_TIME
   ,( SELECT  MIN(Badge_IN_OUT_Time ) from  task_mgmt E where E.UserName =  A.UserName   and A.Task_code =  E.Task_Code and    [Action] ='END'  )  Badge_OUT_TIME
  , SUM( [DATEDIFF] ) OVER (PARTITION BY  UserName, Task_Code, [Action]  order by  UserName ) as  Total_MinsSpend
 FROM 
  (
   SELECT 
   Task_sn
 , UserName
 , Task_Code
 , [Action]
 , Badge_IN_OUT_Time 
 , ISNULL( LEAD(Badge_IN_OUT_Time) over  (Partition by UserName, Task_Code order by UserName ), '2021-07-20 12:30:00.000') as [StartTime_Lead]
 ,  DATEDIFF ( MINUTE,Badge_IN_OUT_Time ,iSNULL( LEAD(Badge_IN_OUT_Time) over  (Partition by UserName, Task_Code order by UserName ), '2021-07-20 12:30:00.000')  ) as [DATEDIFF] --Get the date dfference  
  FROM  task_mgmt
  )
 AS A Where A.[Action]  in ('Start')
```

[image: Result]

Comment: JSLover Can you please have a look in my answer and clarify these points. 
Add the derivation details for the Badge_IN_TIME Badge_OUT_TIME columns in  your question or as a comment. So I can try to get these column values as well.  You have explained the calculation for TOTAL_MINS_SPENT nicely. Do the same for Badge_IN_TIME Badge_OUT_TIME as well as I am not sure about what you need to display there. Thanks

Comment: In our current table we have only one column badge-in an badge-out and we do a difference by referring to the Action (START, END).

Comment: If the Action value is "START" + Badge_IN_OUT_TIME = Badge_In_Time. 
If the Action value is "END" + Badge_IN_OUT_TIME = Badge_Out_Time.

Comment: But in output, we would like to show the latest Badge_In and Badge_Out time.

Comment: @JSLover I thing the Total_Mins_spend is correct as I added :)

Comment: Little bit confusing, If you can show me how you get the Badge in Time for User "Andy" it would be great for me. I can add the solution there @JSLover

Comment: @JSLover How the BAdge In time is greater than Badge out time as shown in the expected result, How the second record does not have any out time for badge?  I have doubts in the two columns. And one more if you feel this solution is helpful atleast vote please. The result should satisfy the logic which is not happening for the above tow columns as they are not in line with data.